# Postfix - enable_long_queue_ids assures unique QueueIDs?

Tags: logging, postfix-mta

I want to aggregate log lines by QueueIDs.  As far as my understanding of postfix, when `enable_long_queue_ids= no`
queueIds are ensured to be unique within the lifetime of a message, and for the second the queueID is created.  This means a queueid could be reuse once a message has been processed.

I wonder if setting `enable_long_queue_ids = yes` would ensure uniqueness of queids accross log statements, beyond the lifetime of a message.

Answer (score 4):

```
enable_long_queue_ids = yes
```

Ensures longer queue IDs (queue file names). Of course the number of possible queue ids is finite, but for all practical purposed the will be unique for a longer period of time (like 5 days).

Comment: since long_queue_ids use 30lower bits of unix epochs, wouldnt this assure uniqueness within a long extended period of time i.e: 30 years?

Comment: @DavidPrzybilla Where did you get that `long_queue_ids` uses 30 lower bits of unix epoch ? I can't find this anywhere.